# Clojure output binding reset in for loop

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm new to Clojure, and am trying to redirect output to a file by rebinding `*out*`. In a simple case, it works nicely:

```
(binding [*out* (new java.io.FileWriter "test.txt")]
  (println "Hi"))
```

This does what I expect, printing "Hi" to the file test.txt. However, if I introduce a `for` loop, things go awry:

```
(binding [*out* (new java.io.FileWriter "test.txt")]
  (for [x [1 2]]
    (println "Hi" x)))
```

This time, all the output goes to stdout, and the file is empty. What's going on here?

I'm using Leiningen, if that makes any difference:

```
Leiningen 2.0.0 on Java 1.7.0_13 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I removed the comment as I just *knew* it wouldn't work. Original comments was: `(doseq [x [1 2]] (println "Hi" x))`

Comment: @Kyle Actually, it *does* work. You should be more confident :) So it must a be a lazy sequence thing ... would appreciate more insight though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have been bitten by the lazy bug.

put a `doall` or `dorun` around the for and within the binding

```
(binding [*out* (new java.io.FileWriter "test.txt")]
  (doall (for [x [1 2]]
           (println "Hi" x))))
```

In your example the printing is happening then the result is printed by the repl *after* it is returned from the binding. So at the time of printing the binding is no longer in place.

Nothing is printed because result is a lazy sequence that will later be evaluated when used

```
user> (def result (binding [*out* (new java.io.FileWriter "test.txt")]
        (for [x [1 2]] 
          (println "Hi" x))))
#'user/result
```

When the repl prints the resuls the printlns are evaluated:

```
user> result
(Hi 1
Hi 2 
nil nil)
```

If we force the evaluation of the lazy sequence returned by `for` within the binding
nothing is printed to the repl,

```
user> (def result (binding [*out* (new java.io.FileWriter "test.txt")]
  (doall (for [x [1 2]]             
          (println "Hi" x))))) 
#'user/result 
user> result
(nil nil)
```

and instead the output ends up in the file:

```
arthur@a:~/hello$ cat test.txt 
Hi 1
Hi 2
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification. Also worth noting is that replacing `for` with `doseq` works as well.